# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected metabox.php custon-sidebar

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

I performed a migration of the approval of the production server to wordpress and ended up giving problem in a plugin called "custom-sidebar" the following message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_GLOBAL in **/home/storage/c/ff/92/sindpfpr/public_html/wp-content/plugins/custom-sidebars/views/metabox.php on line 2** follows the code where it is pointing the error and I am very grateful to those who help me in this problem, thanks

```
<?php
/**
 * Metabox inside posts/pages where user can define custom sidebars for an
 * individual post.
 */

global $wp_registered_sidebars;

$available = $wp_registered_sidebars;
$sidebars = CustomSidebars::get_options( 'modifiable' );
?>

<p>
    <?php _e(
        'Here you can replace the default sidebars. Simply select what ' .
        'sidebar you want to show for this post!', CSB_LANG
    ); ?>
</p>

<?php if ( ! empty( $sidebars ) ) { ?>
    <?php foreach ( $sidebars as $s ) { ?>
        <?php $sb_name = $available[ $s ]['name']; ?>
        <p>
            <b><?php echo esc_html( $sb_name ); ?></b>:
            <select name="cs_replacement_<?php echo esc_attr( $s ); ?>">
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php foreach ( $available as $a ) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $a['id'] ); ?>" <?php selected( $selected[ $s ], $a['id'] ); ?>>
                    <?php echo esc_html( $a['name'] ); ?>
                </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </p>
    <?php
    }
} else {
    ?>
    <p id="message" class="updated">
        <?php _e(
            'All sidebars have been locked, you cannot replace them. ' .
            'Go to <a href="widgets.php">the widgets page</a> to unlock a ' .
            'sidebar', CSB_LANG
        ); ?>
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is because of the global declaration when it is already in a global scope.  You only use global declarations inside functions/methods.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

However, it is bad practice to use global variables inside functions and I don't recommend doing so.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I'm only using the plugin, I've used it in aws and on my pc and it worked, only appeared in hosting this problem

Comment: @user2350939 Well it may be due to different versions enforcing different standards but it is not proper code to have that global declaration. Have you tried commenting out the global declaration at the top to see if that fixes the problem?  The error message is obviously about the global.